# I am trying create a VIEW with this query but doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a VIEW with this query but it doesn't work, why? no error is displayed.

I am using phpmyadmin to try to create

> query

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'ifnull(SUM(case when `subjectQuestion` = ''',
      `subjectQuestion`,
      ''' then `Nota` end),0) AS `',
      `subjectQuestion`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  cs_notasQuestionSubjectStudent;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `codAluno`, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM cs_notasQuestionSubjectStudent 
                   GROUP BY codAluno');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I don't see any `CREATE VIEW` statement?

Comment: @stickybit I am using phpmyadmin to create it

Comment: You can run your statement without building a view and see if the build select statement is buggy. but i don't think that you can build so a view, a stored procedure a function ok, but views are something different.

Comment: @nbk when I run it works ok. the problem is building a view.

Comment: as i said try your statement as procedure, a view is define as CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t; no stmt allowed i think

Comment: I'll try it, thanks @nbk